# Extract part of a string in excel cell

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet

I have an excel spreadsheet in which there is a column containing a specific string. I need to extract part of that string in another column.

The data is as follows:

```
Column A 
---------------------------------
FIS/SIFT/SBG091241012FIS/SIFT/SBG091241012
FIS/SIFT/SBG091311212FIS/SIFT/SBG09111212
..
...
```

Is there any formula in excel through which i can extract the last part of string after forward slash (/). In the above example these are:

```
SBG091241012
SBG09111212
```

Please note that the last part of string after slash (/) is variable length so we may not be able to use the **=RIGHT** function in excel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this function ..

```
Function GetTail(r As Range) As String
Dim s As String

s = r.Value
GetTail = Mid(s, InStrRev(s, "/") + 1)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Though the above answer is perfect. But in case you like Right function for any reason:

Right(str, Len(str) - InStrRev(str, "/", -1, vbTextCompare))